# memory exhausted in getting user data in doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2 and zend 1.11 in my project.
I have a user entity which is related to many other entities like events, conference, documents.. so  user is having many onetomany relationships..

So first the user has to login and than he can suggest an event or confernce or any other.. 
so this is one to many relationship..

now my problem is if for particular user he has entered lots of conf and event and others.. than now when the user suggests new event than at the moment of saving the event i get the logged in user id and than from that i get the entity user. as the event is expecting user_id as of type entity user. i have to get the user entity by the loggedin id. So while getting the user it gets all its related data which takes lots of time and memory.

thanks in advance.. what to do..

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate way to achieve what you want is using [`LAZY`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-lazy-loading) association fetching. See [Doctrine Manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) for details (specifiaclly, `fetch` attribute)